# Передается только 1 option

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, выполняю post запрос, но передается только client, waiter не передается. В чем может быть проблема?

```
function saveorder($i)
{
//Получаем параметры
var text = $('#semiprod').val();
var waiter = document.getElementById('waiter');
var waiter_value = waiter.options[waiter.selectedIndex].text;
var client = document.getElementById('client');
var client_value = client.options[client.selectedIndex].text;

   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/fun/addorder.php",
            data: "waiter="+ waiter_value,
            data: "client="+ client_value,  
            success: function(html) {
                    $("#response3").empty();
$("#div222").load("ord_table.php");
                    $("#response3").append(html);
            }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не следует несколько раз объявлять в объекте одно и то же свойство. Последнее значение перепишет все остальные.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/fun/addorder.php",
  data: {
    waiter: waiter_value,
    client: client_value
  },
  success: function(html) {
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.